# Fetched objects returned by NSFetchRequest are not in the proper section

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

No matter what I put as the value in `sectionNameKeyPath: "value"`, the fetched objects get returned in the order in which they were saved in the database. The number of sections is correct, but whether I view the fetched objects by section `fetchedResultsController.sections` or `fetchedResultsController.object(at: indexPath)` I get the same results.

**This is in the UITableViewController**

```
lazy var fetchedResultsController: NSFetchedResultsController<Dice> = {
    let fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<Dice> = Dice.fetchRequest()

    fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "createdAt", ascending: false)]

    let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
    let context = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext

    // Doesn't matter what I set in the "sectionNameKeyPath" value
    let fetchedResultsController = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: fetchRequest, managedObjectContext: context, sectionNameKeyPath: "set.identifier", cacheName: nil)

    fetchedResultsController.delegate = self

    return fetchedResultsController
}()
```

Has anyone else seen this?

Comment: The first sort descriptor must be based on the section name key path (or at least generate the same relative order).

Comment: @JoakimDanielson I have `Dice` that have a `createdAt` property which I want to sort by. They belong to a `Dice Set` in the `set` property of the individual dice. Each `Dice Set` has an identifier which I want to section the `Dice` by. So the sectionNameKeyPath `set.identifier` refers to the Dice Set id.